# How do i get an amount per page in Ajax/php/sql

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax

I have a problem to get an amount per page. I use a script with items per page (60 pieces) but I want to have the option to choose an amount.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){ 
                function loading_show(){
                    $('#loading').html("<img src='./img/loading.gif'/>").fadeIn('fast');
                }
                function loading_hide(){
                    $('#loading').fadeOut('fast');
                }                 
                function loadData(page){
                    loading_show();                    
                    $.ajax
                    ({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "load_data.php",
                        data: "page="+page,
                        success: function(msg)
                        {
                            $("#container").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
                            {
                                loading_hide();
                                $("#container").html(msg);
                                //Put code here like so
                                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 1000);                                
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
                loadData(1);  // For first time page load default results
                $('#container .pagination li.active').live('click',function(){
                    var page = $(this).attr('p');
                    loadData(page);

                });
                $("#aantal").live('change',function(){
                    var aantal = $('#aantal :selected').val();
                    alert('Aantal per pagina:'+aantal);
                    // alert('hello');
                }); 
                $('#go_btn').live('click',function(){
                    var page = parseInt($('.goto').val());
                    var no_of_pages = parseInt($('.total').attr('a'));
                    if(page != 0 && page <= no_of_pages){
                        loadData(page);  
                    }else{
                        alert('Enter a PAGE between 1 and '+no_of_pages);
                        $('.goto').val("").focus();
                        return false;
                    }
                });                
            });
        </script>
```

This is the selectbox:

```
<select name='aantal' class='aantal' id='aantal'>
          <option value='10'>10</option>
          <option value='60' selected='selected'>60</option>
          <option value='1000'>all</option>
        </select>
```

And this is the load function.

```
<?php
if($_POST['page'])
{
$page = $_POST['page'];
$cur_page = $page;
$page -= 1;
$per_page = ($_POST["aantal"] <> "" && is_numeric($_GET["aantal"]) ) ? intval($_GET["aantal"]) : 60;
$previous_btn = true;
$next_btn = true;
$first_btn = true;
$last_btn = true;
$start = $page * $per_page;
include"db.php";
?>
```

When I do, I get the alert box. But how can I select amount per page?

Comment: Totally irrelevant to your question, but I'd advise you not to mix languages in your script (eg. `aantal` and `page`). Best practice is to use only english variable/function names, comments etc. Adds to readability, even for yourself, as all programming languages use english terms for native functions. Of course any front-end strings (text seen by your end-users) can be in any language you want! (Or any language your user wants ;))

Answer (score 1):

You need to send the value of the select box to your php load function. Just modify the `data` key to include it

```
$.ajax
({
    type: "POST",
    url: "load_data.php",
    data: {"page": page, "aantal": $('#aantal').val()}
    ...
```